# Stop Braintree paypal in modal opening in new tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, braintree

I need to make PayPal show in model, when user presses it's button, right now it just open new tab, which is not great UX.

Didn't find that in documentation

Answer (score 6):

<sub>I am a developer at Braintree. 
Let me know if you have any other questions at support@braintreepayments.com</sub>

Braintree's Pay with PayPal integration will always force a pop-up window hosted on a PayPal domain in all the environments and browsers that support it. This means that you cannot make PayPal appear in a modal; whether it does or not will be decided based on the browser you are using. The reason for this is that it provides a higher level of verifiability if you can see the PayPal domain name in your browser's location bar.

The Braintree docs will be updated to reflect this.

Comment: But Twilio also uses Braintree and have PayPal in modal